# python first argument of .insert cannot be 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, insert

This was just a challenge I made up for myself and it's really annoying. Would appreciate your help very much. I get the error saying on line 5 "'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer" for insert method but it checks and verifies at the top that the items in the list are int, which was unnecessery but I though just maybe I was wrong.

```
d = list(range(88))
print (type(d[4]))
for i in d:
    if i % 8 == 0:
        d.insert(d[i], "XOX")
    
print(d)
```

Comment: try printing the value of `d[i]` every iteration, you will find out why that error happens ... you are modifying d.

Comment: I guess I get it. After the first insertion, next iteration tries to take the first arg of insert as the previously inserted string, which cannot be interpreted as an integer. Right?

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Comment: You're great with that quick reply, you saved me a lot of mind-burning thoughts, man. As I said, I appreciate it so much. Take care!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make you understand, see the below code:

```
d = list(range(88))
print("d is:\n", d)
for i in d:
    print("i is :", i)
    if i % 8 == 0:
        d.insert(d[i], "XOX")
    print("Now d is: ", d)
```

#output:

```
d is:
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87]
i is : 0
Now d is:  ['XOX', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87]
i is : 0
```

When `'XOX'` is inserted at `0th` position, i value is again 0 since 0 is shifted towards right. Now, `d[0]` becomes `'XOX'` that's why you get error.

Comment: I found out there is an accept as an answer option upon your comment! That's enough discovering for now I guess